# how to disable scrolling when a finger is in the bottom of the touchpad

Tags: synaptic

I like to select text with the touchpad by clicking the Left-Bottom button and dragging with the other finger across the touchpad.

The problem is that my client scrolls before selecting text. I want to only be able to select text. How do I disable scrolling on the bottom of the touchpad.